# How does Encfs work?

Tags: encryption

I cannot understand the idea behind Encfs. Even ready example, offered by my Ubuntu, does not work for me:

> encfs ~/crypt ~/.crypt

There is an error:

> unable to locate a mount point

Should I initialize the files somehow? What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I use encfs since 2009 and until now every day, I will make a quick how to :

### **What you need for make it work ?**

fuse and encfs only, they can be found directly in your package management

```
Debian : apt-get install encfs
Fedora : yum install encfs
Gentoo : emerge encfs
```

...

*(select only encfs will install dependencies automatically)*

### **How do I create a crypted directory ?**

If you want to use encfs with your user (no root), you must add fuse on the group of this one first. Open a terminal and log in root :

```
adduser youruser fuse
```

*replace youruser by your.*

Once add, kill and restart X or just reboot your computer.

Now open a terminal (in user $) :

```
groups
```

If you see fuse, then you can create the directory now by this command :

```
encfs /home/youruser/.crypt/ /home/youruser/crypt
```

*.crypt and crypt directory must not exist, if they exist, delete them or choice another path*

The first time, it will display as follow :

> The directory "/home/youruser/.crypt/" does not exist. Should it be
>   created? (y,n) y
>   The directory "/home/youruser/crypt" does not exist.
>   Should it be created? (y,n) y
>   Please choose from one of the following
>   options:  enter "x" for expert configuration mode,  enter "p" for
>   pre-configured paranoia mode,  anything else, or an empty line will
>   select standard mode. ?> p
>   New Encfs Password:
>   Verify Encfs Password:

*As showed, answer -> first y | second y | third p*

Once created, the directory crypt is mounted (by default), add files inside crypt directory. For make them unreadable  :

```
fusermount -u /home/youruser/crypt
```

This will unmount the directory crypt, all the file inside "disappear" and can be found encrypted on the directory .crypt :

```
ls /home/youruser/.crypt/
```

Will display something like (3 files on this example) :

```
0WoRsjyzZHI,Un-198TRY-dU  91rj264Z09Jcz7XZ4sbDeYfd  KpJTDI2TVUEFHTkksqxPT9xu
```

For get back your crypted file readable, do :

```
encfs /home/youruser/.crypt /home/youruser/crypt
```

Will output a prompt requiring your password

### **How do I backup the crypted file, and open them to another computer / server**

Be aware, except your encrypted file, you absolutely need to backup the file encfs6.xml which contain your encoded password and his salt generation.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29

this file can be found :

```
/home/youruser/.crypt/.encfs6.xml
```

Best way to backup your crypted data in a proper way :

```
tar cvzf CryptedBackup.tar.gz /home/youruser/.crypt/
```

With the backup, on your other computer/server just unpack it to the /home/user/ and create the mount point (mkdir /home/user/crypt) and it  will work.

Careful, if you lost your password, or if your encfs6.xml is missing, is no way to get back your encrypted

Answer (score 1):

It will give you this error if **both** of the conditions are trues:

- `~/crypt` **is not a directory** (e.g. is missing, or a non-directory called `~/crypt` already exists), *and*
- `~/crypt` **cannot be created** by encfs (mkdir would fail, e.g. permissions issues, or a non-directory called `~/crypt` already exists)

See the source code at http://code.google.com/p/encfs/source/browse/trunk/encfs/main.cpp?spec=svn27&r=27

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're mixing up the directories. **~/crypt** and **~/.crypt** must both be existing directories where the first parameter to encfs will be the store, where the encrypted files will be stored by encfs and the second parameter is the place where you want to place your files you want to be encrypted.

See also [here](http://www.movingtofreedom.org/2007/02/21/howto-encfs-encrypted-file-system-in-ubuntu-and-fedora-gnu-linux/) for a guide on how to set up and use encfs.